# Command line rename of dot file

Tags: cmd

I am trying to rename a directory from ".Hidden" to "Hidden" using the command line to include in a batch file.  I can rename Hidden to .Hidden, but cannot rename it back to start with a dot.  Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is limited to questions about *software development*, or tools exclusively for that use. Questions about simply using OS-provided tools are generally a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to post a comment, but I tried with **`REN`** command and all works as expected.

My process was only something like this:

```bat
mkdir MyDir

rem # This works:
ren MyDir .MyDir 

rem # To check results:
dir 

rem # This also works:
ren .MyDir MyDir 

rem # Again:
dir
```